# $ f $ is differentiable in $ (0,0). $

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Definition: Let $V\subseteq{\mathbb{R}^{m}}$ an open set, $a\in V$ y  $f\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ a function. We will say that $f$ is differentiable in $a,$ if exists a linear transformation $f'(a)\colon\mathbb{R}^{m}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$
such that
\begin{equation}
f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)(h)+r(h),\qquad\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\dfrac{r(h)}{\lVert h\rVert}}=0.
\end{equation}

Let $ a \in \mathbb {R}$ be. Define the function $ f \colon \mathbb {R}^ {2} \to \mathbb {R} $ given by

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{x\sin^{2}(x)+axy^{2}}{x^{2}+2y^{2}+3y^{4}} & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 
0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}

Find the value of $ a $ so that $ f $ is differentiable by $ (0,0). $

My attempt:

We observed that

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0).
\end{equation}

If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\{(0,0)\},$ then

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=\dfrac{\sin^{2}(x)(2y^{2}+3y^{4}-x^{2})+x\sin(2x)(x^{2}+2y^{2}+3y^{4})+ay^{2}(2y^{2}+3y^{4}-x^{2})}{(x^{2}+2y^{2}+3y^{4})^{2}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=\dfrac{2axy(x^{2}-3y^{4})-4xy\sin^{2}(x)(1+3y^{2})}{(x^{2}+2y^{2}+3y^{4})^{2}}
\end{equation}

If $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)=0,$ then

\begin{align}
2axy(x^{2}-3y^{4})-4xy\sin^{2}(x)(1+3y^{2})=0&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad a(x^{2}-3y^{4})=2\sin^{2}(x)(1+3y^{2})\\
&\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad a=\dfrac{2\sin^{2}(x)(1+3y^{2})}{x^{2}-3y^{4}}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
f(x,y)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
x\sin^{2}(x) & (x,y)\neq(0,0)\\ 
0 & (x,y)=(0,0)
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=0=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)
\end{equation}

From this it follows that $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)$ are continuous by $(0,0)$ y $f$ is differentiable by $(0,0).$

Are my arguments correct?
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You are asked to find a value of $a$ for which the  derivative exists at the origin. You did not find any.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Consider $a=\dfrac{2\sin^{2}(x)(1+3y^{2})}{x^{2}-3y^{4}}$

Comment: That's not a constant. So any time in your calculations where you took the derivatives assuming it was weren't valid.

Comment: Also your computation for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)$ is incorrect. It should be $1$, not $0$

Comment: @NinadMunshi You're right. What is the correct way to find the value a?

Comment: First, what is the definition of being differentiable in this case?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I just wrote the definition they gave me in class.

Comment: Another way of writing that is if the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)\cdot h}{||h||}$$ exists and equals zero. Can you take it from here? (Hint: What does $Df(a)\cdot h$ look like?)

Comment: The generic partial derivative you take with respect to x is wrong.  What you did is say that $(\frac{g}{h})'=\frac{g'h}{h^2}=\frac{g'}{h}$, which is only true if the denominator is a constant.  What you should have is that $(\frac{g}{h})'=\frac{g'h-gh'}{h^2}$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\dfrac{h\sin^{2}(h)}{h^{2}}}{h} =\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{h\sin^{2}(h)}{h^3}=1$$

$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{\dfrac{0}{2k^{2}+3k^4}}{k} =0$$

then by [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions) we need to check that

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)}\frac{\dfrac{h\sin^{2}(h)+ahk^{2}}{h^{2}+2k^{2}+3k^{4}}-h}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} =\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{h\sin^{2}(h)+ahk^{2}-h^3-2hk^2-3hk^4}{(h^{2}+2k^{2}+3k^{4})\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=0$$

which is true indeed by $a=2$

$$\dfrac{h\sin^{2}(h)+ahk^{2}-h^3-2hk^2-3hk^4}{(h^{2}+2k^{2}+3k^{4})\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=\dfrac{h(h^2+O(h^4))+2hk^{2}-h^3-2hk^2-3hk^4}{(h^{2}+2k^{2}+3k^{4})\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}=$$

$$=\dfrac{-3hk^4+O(h^5)}{(h^{2}+2k^{2}+3k^{4})\sqrt{h^2+k^2}}$$

then use polar coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat different approach:

In order to be differentiable, a function must be continuous and have a continuous derivative (or have a derivative with an essential singularity).  Continuity requires that the limit as you approach the point be the same, regardless of direction of your approach.

Suppose we approach along the line $x=y=\epsilon$.  Then we have (using the fact that $\frac{d}{da}\sin^2(a)=\sin(2a)$:
$$g(\epsilon)=f(\epsilon,\epsilon) = \frac{\epsilon\sin^2(\epsilon)+a\epsilon^3}{\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^2+3\epsilon^4} = \frac{\sin^2(\epsilon)+a\epsilon^2}{3\epsilon+3\epsilon^3}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\sin^2(\epsilon)+a\epsilon^2}{\epsilon+\epsilon^3}$$
$$g'(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{(\epsilon+\epsilon^3)(\sin(2\epsilon)+2a\epsilon)-(\sin^2(\epsilon)+a\epsilon^2)(1+3\epsilon^2)}{\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^4+\epsilon^6} = \frac{1}{3}\frac{\epsilon\sin(2\epsilon)+2a\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3\sin(2\epsilon)+2a\epsilon^4-\sin^2(\epsilon)-a\epsilon^2-3\epsilon^2\sin^2(\epsilon)-3a\epsilon^5}{\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^4+\epsilon^6}$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}g'(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{3}\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{\epsilon\sin(2\epsilon)+2a\epsilon^2+\epsilon^3\sin(2\epsilon)+2a\epsilon^4-\sin^2(\epsilon)-a\epsilon^2-3\epsilon^2\sin^2(\epsilon)-3a\epsilon^5}{\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^4+\epsilon^6} = \frac{1}{3} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin(2\epsilon)+2\epsilon\cos(2\epsilon)+4a\epsilon+3\epsilon^2\sin(2\epsilon)+2\epsilon^3\cos(2\epsilon)+8a\epsilon^3-\sin(2\epsilon)-2a\epsilon-6\epsilon\sin^2(\epsilon)-3\epsilon^2\sin(2\epsilon)-15a\epsilon^4}{2\epsilon+8\epsilon^3+6\epsilon^5} = \frac{1}{3} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{2\epsilon\cos(2\epsilon)+2a\epsilon+2\epsilon^3\cos(2\epsilon)+8a\epsilon^3-6\epsilon\sin^2(\epsilon)-15a\epsilon^4}{2\epsilon+8\epsilon^3+6\epsilon^5} = \frac{1}{3} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{2\cos(2\epsilon)+2a+2\epsilon^2\cos(2\epsilon)+8a\epsilon^2-6\sin^2(\epsilon)-15a\epsilon^3}{2+8\epsilon^2+6\epsilon^4} = \frac{1}{3} \frac{2+2a}{2} = \frac{1+a}{3}$$

Suppose we approach along the line $-x=y=\epsilon$.  Then we have:
$$h(\epsilon)=f(-\epsilon,\epsilon) = \frac{-\epsilon\sin^2(-\epsilon)-a\epsilon^3}{\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^2+3\epsilon^4} = \frac{-\epsilon\sin^2(\epsilon)-a\epsilon^3}{\epsilon^2+2\epsilon^2+3\epsilon^4}= -g(\epsilon)$$
$$h'(\epsilon)=-g'(\epsilon)$$
$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}h'(\epsilon)=-\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0}g'(\epsilon)=-\frac{1+a}{3}$$

In both directions, the limit of the derivative existed, and therefore because the direction of approach doesn't matter, we require that the limits be the same.
$\frac{1+a}{3}=-\frac{1+a}{3}$, which means that $a=-1$.

Comment: A function can be differentiable everywhere without its derivative being continuous.

Comment: @egreg: A discontinuity in the derivative of a differentiable function can only be an essential singularity, not a jump discontinuity, which is what we have here.  I'll make an edit accordingly

Comment: @Moko19 I was able to replicate their accounts and I got $ a = -1, $, but does that guarantee me that the partial derivatives of that function will be continuous? Even with that value, I don't know how to finish the exercise. Would you be offended if I replicated your accounts in the post? I would like to know if there is a result that allows me to guarantee that $ f $ is differentiable with that value.

Comment: It seems there is a mistake here $$\ldots = 
\frac{1}{3} \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0} \frac{\sin(2\epsilon)+2\epsilon\cos(2\epsilon)+4a\epsilon+3\epsilon^2\sin(2\epsilon)\color{red}{+2 \epsilon^3\cos(2\epsilon)}+8a\epsilon^3-\sin(2\epsilon)-2a\epsilon-6\epsilon\sin^2(\epsilon)-3\epsilon^2\sin(2\epsilon)-15a\epsilon^4}{2\epsilon+8\epsilon^3+6\epsilon^5} =\ldots$$ maybe the difference come from here. I've obtained $a=2$ by the definition.

Comment: @Darkmaster: Your function $f$ is a function that is the quotient of two functions that are continuous and infinitely differentiable everywhere (because the are made up of polynomials and the function $\sin(x)$).  This means that any partial derivative of $f$ anywhere but at a zero of the polynomial in the denominator must be continuous.  At a zero of the denominator, the partial derivative must either obtain a single finite value from all direction or diverge.  In our case, it converged and therefore must obtain a single finite value

Comment: @user: Thanks for correcting the error.  As it turns out, that is not a dominating term anyway (it goes to zero much faster that $2\epsilon\cos(2\epsilon)$), so it had no impact on the result